# Add and delete row in React Native listView dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
 class CreateTS extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        project: 'Select Project',
        activity: 'Select Activity',
        hour: '',
        task: '',
        timesheet: [],
        dataSource: []
    };

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.state.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.timesheet);

    console.log('Here at constructo!');
}


onAddTSPress() {
    const { project, activity, task, hour } = this.state;

    console.log(project);
    console.log(activity);
    console.log(task);
    console.log(hour);


    this.setState({
        timesheet: this.state.timesheet.push(project)
    });

    console.log('Here button press!');

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.timesheet);
}

renderRow(data) {
    console.log('Here at render row!');
    console.log(`${data} $""`);
    return <Text> {data} </Text>;
}

render() {
  return(

     Some input components that set state of project and activity with 
     values...
     A button that call onAddTSPress function.
     And a listview in which items will be add that we created above
  );
}
```

After running above code and add one item i got following screen which is expected behavior.
[image]

But when i try to add another item in list i got following error. What is the issue? [image]

it saying push is not a function while first time it run successfully as expected. But second time it gives error and i am unable to add second item in list.

Here is my updated onAddTSPress function

```
   //Modified onAddTSPress function
   onAddTSPress() {
    const { project, activity, task, hour } = this.state;

    console.log(project);
    console.log(activity);
    console.log(task);
    console.log(hour);

    console.log(`${this.state.timesheet}`);
    this.setState({
        timesheet: [...this.state.timesheet, project]
    });

    console.log('Here button press!');
    console.log(`${this.state.timesheet}`);

    this.setState({ dataSource: 
    this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.timesheet) });
 }

 return (
   <Button
                onPress={this.onAddTSPress.bind(this)}
                btnStyle={styles.btnStyle}
                txtStyle={styles.txtStyle}
            >
                Add
            </Button>
            <ListView
                style={styles.listViewContianer}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}
                enableEmptySections
            />


   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `this.state.timesheet.push(project)`, `push` prototype of array return number of record in array after pushed. `push` method not returning latest array and you are setting state with return value of `push` method which are a number. First time it work fine because you initialize timesheet as array (`[]`) and first time `push` method work. But second time when you try to call `push` method of `timesheet`, which is now a number, it will throw array.

#### Solution

You can try `[...this.state.timesheet, project]` instance of push. By this way you will get updated array.

```
this.setState({
    timesheet: [...this.state.timesheet, project]
});
```

**or**

You can keep old value in a variable and push new value and reassign array to setState.

```
const timesheet = this.state.timesheet;
timesheet.push(project);
this.setState({
    timesheet: timesheet
});
```

Also use datasource inside state and update it by setState

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});

this.setState({
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.timesheet)
});
```

Comment: This make sense. But now there is no row rendered in list after first click. (Note:onAddTSPress is click listener of button) First item added in list after second click.

Comment: Keep datasource in state and update it by `setState` method, You are directly updating this.datasource, which is mutable and render don't know about this change.

Comment: Tried. But no luck. I have eidted my `onAddTSPress` function. You may have a look

Comment: I have updated my answer, Try to update datasource from new `ds`.

Answer (score 1):

You should never mutate state directly, instead use following syntax

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  timesheet: [...prevState.timesheet, project]
}))
```

For your comment:

> First item added in list after second click and second after third
>   click and so on

You need to re-render `ListView` on state change. To do so you can either add key like

```
key="this.state.listChanged" // your list state name
```

or

```
(this.state.listChanged)
  ? <ListView />{/* or call your method */}
  : <Text>{/*some message */}</Text>
```

Comment: Just replaced  
        this.setState({
            timesheet: this.state.timesheet.push(project)
        }); with this.setState(prevState => ({
            timesheet: [...prevState.timesheet, project]
        }));
I do not get anything in list on first click. First item added in list after second click and second after third click and so on

Comment: can you please add `onAddTSPress()` call

Comment: I have update my answer hope that should solve your problem of re-rendering